# iOS 17 upgrade - all voicemail (including "deleted") lost

Tags: backup, upgrade, voicemail, ios

iOS 16 -> iOS 17 upgrade

Upgrade seemed to go as expected (this is 3rd phone I've upgraded), but the only one I use as daily driver for phone calls.

All the voicemails are gone, that is, not displayed.

I thought that the message files were stored on phone, (esp. because there is a deleted folder), and because the new messages are synced from the carrier.

Most of the Apple forum posts insist that everything lives with the carrier, but that doesn't make sense to me.

I did do an iCloud backup of the device before I upgraded, but have not tried restoring, in part because I was concerned about how the "backup in iOS16, then restore in iOS17" might go.

Any ides?

Comment: *"backup in iOS16, then restore in iOS17"* is not a problem. Why is it that you think it is?

Comment: Does it put my phone back to iOS16?

Comment: And also, are there versioning problems? Those type of concerns.

Comment: Voicemail is provided by the carrier.  Regardless of what the phone thinks is going on, you should be able to sign into your voicemail at the carrier and retrieve messages.  The phone is just a window.

Comment: Restoring data from an earlier operating system version does not revert the operating system to the previous version. *It just restores the user data.*

Comment: So would that make the voicemails reappear?

Comment: @benc Dial into the carrier and see if they're still there, then worry about whatever the phone might be doing.